# Correlation coefficient between X~N(0,1) and $Y=X^{n}$

Tags: normal-distribution, correlation

> Assume $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y = X^{n}$, where $n$ is a positive integer. Find $\rho_{xy}$ (correlation coefficient of $X$ and $Y$)

The only result that I have been able to find is:
$$E[Y^{2n}] = \frac{(2n)!}{n!2^{n}}$$
But I can't proceed to finding the variance. If I could find the variance of Y, that is, the variance of the nth power of a standard normally distributed variable, then I could easily find the correlation.

I think it has something to do with moments and cumulants, but I can't make the exact connection.

The answer is:

$$
\rho_{xy} =
\begin{cases}
 \frac{n!!}{\sqrt{(2n-1)!!}}, & \text{if $n$ is odd} \\
 0, & \text{if $n$ is even} 
\end{cases}
$$

Thank you guys!

Comment: The variance of $Y$ is $E(X^{2n})-E(X^n)^2$, so, what is stopping you?

Comment: damnn I forgot about that simple property of variance! It simplifies alot, very helpful, thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the definition of the correlation coefficient,

$$\rho = {E(XY) - E(X) E(Y) \over SD(X) SD(Y)}$$

Since $Y = X^n$, this becomes

$$\rho = {E(X^{n+1}) - E(X) E(X^n) \over SD(X) SD(X^n)} $$

Now of course $E(X) = 0$ and $SD(X) = 1$ since $X$ is standard normal.  So you have

$$ \rho = {E(X^{n+1}) \over SD(X^n)}$$

Now you just need to work out the numerator and denominator.  Depending on whether $n$ is even or odd you'll get different results.

Comment: Now I got it!, Thanks very much, man!